# Segregate Data in Log files

Tags: logs, aix, data

I want to segregate error types in my log file. I am unable to make a logic for it. Suppose i have these different types of errors in a log file. Now i want to extract those types only. Like in below mentioned log sample, i have three types of errors HTTP Error, Socket Time Out, Invalid parameters. I have many more like these. How can i extract the list for all errors? Please guide.

> ```
> Aug  1 04:41:47 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[17760440]: An HTTP error occurred.
> Aug  1 04:41:47 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[17760440]: Socket Timed out'.
>
> Aug  1 04:41:47 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[17760440]: Invalid Parameters'.
> ```

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the problem. What keeps you from using e.g. `grep`? Try

```
grep "An HTTP error occurred." path/to/logfile
```

and redirect the result to an adequate file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you want to see only those three strings, then ask `grep` for them:

```
grep -E ": An HTTP error occurred\.\$|: Socket Timed out'\.\$|: Invalid Parameters'\.\$" input
```

I've anchored the texts a bit by forcing each of them to start with colon-space (`:`) as well as forcing them to be at the end of the line `$`.  The period and `$` are escaped because I used double-quotes around the grep parameter, due to the single-quotes appearing in the search text.